# Visual Studio build failing and not showing any error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I have created simple `Console.WriteLine` function, on building it says build failed. But doesnt show any error / warning

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you understand _why_ it doesn't compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case I fixed this by **restarting my PC**

Answer (score -1):

Check your build output. Sometimes you will have information about the error in the output.
example: [image]

Comment: I ve already shared the build logs :3, check the second image first